# How to fetch the div content and append in this case

Tags: jquery

With in a for loop , i am checking if a div already exists with particualr id (lastwrap703 in my case) exists under mycontainer .

If so , i am fetching its HTML of the entire lastwrap703 and append that to the string and append that to the newcontainer

https://jsfiddle.net/fpzeLa0a/3/

So that the newcontainer looks like this

```
<div id="newcontainer">

   <div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent703">    
     <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap703" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>First Item</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent644">    
    <div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap644" data-lastwrapquan="0">
         <h3>Second Item</h3>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The issue i am facing is that , in case the item already exists ,

i am unable to add that to the current

```
<div class="TreeMenu_Content" >
```

Please let me know how to add to the existing  in this case .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Thanks , but the lastwrap should be appended to the TreeMenu_Content

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r7kotpnf/1/ ?

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r7kotpnf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a jQuery object based construct like

```
function check() {
    var id = ["703", "405"];
    var $items = $(),
        $el, $item;
    for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        $item = $('<div />', {
            className: "TreeMenu_Content",
            id: "itemcontent" + id[i]
        })
        $el = $("#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id[i]);
        if ($el.length) {
            $item.html($el.contents());
            $el.remove();
        } else {
            $item.html('<div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap' + id + '" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Some Item</h3></div>');
        }
        $items = $items.add($item)
    }
    $("#newcontainer").append($items);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r7kotpnf/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this script. Appends the html to the new container.
  check()

```
    function check()
    {
    var id = ["703","405"];
    var itemshtml = '';
    for(var i=0;i<id.length;i++)
       {
          var exists = $("#mycontainer #lastwrap" + id[i]).length;

          if (exists == 1)
            {
              var itemshtml =  '<div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent'+id[i]+'">';
             // i want to extract the content of lastwrap703 and append to the above 
              $("#newcontainer").append($("#mycontainer #lastwrap"+id[i]).html());
              break;
             }
            else  if (exists == 0) // doesn't exist
             {
               itemshtml += '<div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent'+id+'"><div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap'+id[i]+'" data-lastwrapquan="0"><h3>Some Items</h3></div>';
              $("#newcontainer").append(itemshtml);
             }
   }
```

Comment: but the content inside the <div id="newcontainer> is not matching with the question i posted .